# How to create a table with nested and repeated columns in BigQuery using Java Client library?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I need to create an empty table with nested and repeated columns in BigQuery using Java client library.

We can create the empty table with schema using [Creating and Using Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/tables)

How to create an empty table with repeated columns in BigQuery using Java Client library?

Comment: What is the problem? Try executing a DDL statement instead and update your question if you run into problems: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language

Comment: Hi  Elliott, Thanks for answering. How to perform DDL statement using Java Client library? That is my need?

Comment: You need to run a query. See the examples in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#bigquery-query-java

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#bigquery-query-java

Comment: Hi Elliot,  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#bigquery-query-java shows how to create a table from Select Query. My intention is to create a table from Java Application. Can you advise me on how to do that?

Comment: Yes, you use CREATE TABLE instead of SELECT.